# Grails Spring Security Pre Check Plain password before authentication

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, custom-authentication

I am using a grails spring security core 1.2.7.3 plugin for user login. Now I have a requirement where I need to do a password check before authentication.

When user enters username and password in the login form and submit, I need to have the access to username and plain password entered and do a custom check on the password and do a redirect if the password doesn't match the required pattern, otherwise continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the custom check?? Spring security lets you define a RegEx for your passwords... why dont you use that?

Comment: I need to do a password check during login before authentication.

Comment: I believe you can do this with a filter. Create a filter to do the password check data 'before' submission to Spring Security function